# Standard errors with delta method

Tags: r, regression, autoregressive, delta-method, dynamic-regression

Trying to recreate other author's results. E.g. [this paper](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3329512). Introduction to the model is on page 10, while table with results is presented on page 13. Under the table there's a small note that SE were calculated via "delta method".

---

I am estimating a model: $\log{Y_{it}}= \alpha \cdot dummy_{it} + \beta_1\log{Y_{it-1}}+\beta_2\log{X_{it}}+u_{it}$ where $dummy_{it}$ is a binary variable indicating some kind of policy introduction. I am using autoregressive term, and therefore I can capture both short-run and long-run effect of the policy. The short-run is given by $\alpha$ while the long-run is $\frac{\alpha}{1-\beta_1}$. Standard error for the short run is printed by R. But to get standard errors for the long-run effect, author suggests using "delta method" and is not saying anything else.

---

Want to know how to calculate the standard errors in such a setting. Ideally both, "on paper" and in R using the "delta method".

---

So far I have tried `alr3` package and its `deltaMethod()` function. I tend get to the right estimate but the SE is 0.00000. And when using `msm` package and its `deltamethod()` function I also get 0. Does that mean the SE is so minimal? I don't think so, as the author reports a higher value.

Comment: Could you edit your question and include a reference to the paper you mentioned?

Comment: Link to the example paper added.

Comment: https://www.jepusto.com/multivariate-delta-method/

Comment: This paper has a nice range of worked out examples in R, including for this long-run equation, https://fbe.unimelb.edu.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0005/2704649/2037_Joe-Hirschberg_Fieller-Examples-WP-version.pdf.